# How to handle a post with multiple issues

Tags: discussion, flagging

If someone posts an unreferenced answer saying that people didn't walk on the moon, I'd flag it for lacking references. However, it wouldn't be hate speech.

If someone posts an unreferenced answer (or an answer citing unreliable sources) stating "Jews did 9/11", I'd want to flag it both for containing hate speech, and for lacking references.

However, if I flag a question as "Rude and abusive", I can't create a custom flag immediately afterwards for the lack of references issue.

How should I handle a post that has multiple issues? Use the custom moderator attention box for both the hate speech and the lack of reliable references?

Comment: @Downvoter what's wrong with my question?

Comment: I just think it's an obvious question.  If you have multiple reasons to want a question deleted, then you can just pick _one_, and if a moderator agrees, it will be deleted all the same.  The end goal is to get the question removed, and I get a little bit frustrated when people lose sight of that end goal and get carried away with minor stuff like how the flag is annotated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think an answer should be deleted, then flag it for the biggest reason that you think it should be deleted for.  Even if a moderator deems that specific reason invalid, if it should be deleted for other reasons, then the moderator will probably delete the question anyway.

If you believe that multiple non-deletion actions need to be taken, then you can make a custom flag.

You are also able to take action yourself, so if a question needs editing, you can do your own edits, etc.

---

On another note, If you think that an answer is insufficiently sourced, or otherwise weak or incorrect, then you just need to downvote that answer.  If lack of sources is the only reason you're flagging it, your flag is likely to get declined.